# Analog telephone circuit and TEA1062

Tags: microcontroller, communication, telephone, line

I am currently working on an analog telephone project.

I have some questions.

ICs and Central are below:

1. Central: KX-NS500 (gives 28VDC)
2. DTMF receiver: MT8870
3. DTMF generator: HT9200B
4. MCU: STM32WB10CCU5
5. Line Mng. IC:  TEA1062AT
6. Power IC: 3V3 fixed SMPS

Below is my circuit diagram with some details;

2. DTMF receiver

[image]

Here is the DTMF receiver with MT8870 IC. I built the transistor circuits because the datasheet says the IC's typical Vdd = 5.0V however it works fine with 3V3.

3. DTMF generator

[image]

Here is the tone generator circuit. It works in parallel mode.

4. MCU

[image]

Here is MCU circuit diagram. Some keypads and GPIOs.

5. Line (TEA1062AT)!!!

[image]

Here are the TEA1062AT and line connection. J2 stands for "Hook Switch" and J3 for "Line Input".

Here I have some problems.

First of all, when I supply all other ICs (receiver, generator, MCU) with 3V3 from the power supply (isolated from the TEA1062AT's Vcc) all of them work fine. I can send and receive DTMF tones.

When I try to supply using the TEA1062At VCC pin (the datasheet says you can use this pin to supply peripherals,) the current from this pin is not being enough.

When I upload empty code to MCU, I have stable 3.32V @VCC from TEA. (VCC_Line net) but when I try to send and receive some data from the MCU to the generator and receiver, that 3.32V oscillates. I tried to increase the current capability by lowering R114 and by increasing R93. It did not work.

Then I tried get fixed fixed 3V3 voltage by using the circuit below:

[image]

I take supply for this circuit from after R87 (voltage drop here is approximately 9V,) It works. This time I could not get the DTMF tone from TEA1062 line pin.

Ok.

- Is there any way to supply all peripherals without/with TEA1062AT?
- How can I interface with Central - TEA1062 IC?
- What is wrong in these circuits?

Comment: note the stm32 should easily be able to generate and decode DTMF via software without needing extra chips.

Comment: @Kartman I think the OP will still use an MCU to generate the DTMF signal (sch is unreadable but this is what I understood). The main intention is to carry the DTMF signal over the phone line. So the same line will be used to carry both audio and the DTMF. If somehow I misunderstood what you said, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, TEA1062(A) is dead. It's been obsolete for years so you should get rid of it if you plan for serial production. Last time I designed a TEA1062-based circuit was 6 or 7 years ago and the company was trying to find and purchase the last TEA1062(A) chips on Earth! A Taiwan-based company (I'm not gonna give their name) "copied" Philip's original TEA1062(A) chip. I don't know if they still manufacture and sell 1062s, but personally, I wouldn't trust those copy chips to be honest.

Anyway, your line circuitry looks problematic. You can't use a DC voltage directly through a resistor for LN supply of the chip. Here's the circuit I used in my designs:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f2zVOs.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Build this and use in your design. And everything will be fine.

NOTE: 8V source should be able to supply at least 1A.